# Property "CMemCacheServerConfiguration.connectionID" is not defined

Tags: php, caching, yii, memcached, yii-components

When I activate memcached in Yii this error message raised

Property "CMemCacheServerConfiguration.connectionID" is not defined.

How to resolve this error?

Here's my configuration:

```
  ...
    'cache'=>array(
        'class'=>'CMemCache',
        'servers'=>array(array('host'=>'localhost','port'=>11211,'weight'=>60,),
        ),),
        ....
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

..hmmmm I am confused about your trailing array commas, is there more code ?

```
'cache'=>array( 
            'class'=>'CMemCache',
            'servers'=>array( 
    array('host'=>'localhost','port'=>11211,'weight'=>60)))
```

Comment: Thanks, i've relayout array trailing, but that's not the problem :(